# parsing multiple ints from one input

Tags: java

I am supposed to program something that allows the user to enter input which should be a series of integers, separated by spaces, with no non-number/non-space characters.

What's the best way to do this? Do I take the whole string and split it into an array somehow and check each one?

Comment: Is this homework? I think your first idea is quite good, so give it a try and tell us what (eventual) problems you encountered.

Comment: Your idea is solid, and you can check in the String javadocs for some ideas for how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and specifically [`Scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) and [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) for this.

Have a look at the documentation, but using a scanner one can easily get tokenized integers from the input, and it parses them to `int`s for you!

Answer (score 0):

this is what I used

```
int getInputInt(){
   final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   int inputInt = 0;
boolean continueLoop = true;
while( continueLoop = true ) {
  try{
  inputInt= keyboard.nextInt();
  continueLoop = false;
  break;
  } catch ( InputMismatchException e ) {
  keyboard.nextLine();
  out.println("That key is not an integer. Try again");
  }
}
return inputInt;
   }
```

Comment: You shouldn't feed answers to homework tagged questions, as the tag-wiki mentions: `This lets potential answerers know that they SHOULD guide the student in solving the problem, and SHOULD NOT simply show the complete answer.`

Comment: I'll keep it in mind, but this isn't a full answer anyway.. I don't believe it will work perfectly considering the user must input a multi-integer string

Comment: Giving students code isn't going to help them learn anything @techjunkie.css

Comment: everyone calm down this party is getting out of control

Answer (score 0):

The Code snippet has errors in it.

1] While in java won't allow initialization.

2] The method should return an array of int. Hence, you do a hasNextInt and store the nextInt in the array.